# How to access one application scope from a separate application in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, scope

I have my own answer to this question, which I'll post, but I wanted to see if I missed a simpler way.  I have two application's running on the same coldfusion server, and I want to access the application scope of one from the other.  How might I do this?

UPDATE:

After Reading @Daniel and @Ben's answers, I went back and approached my problem from the standpoint of sub-applications which turned out to be a better solution to my initial problem.  My answer is still the "quick and dirty" way to access other application scopes, but putting data in the server scope is a better practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should probably think about why it is that you want to do this... Architecturally this doesn't seem very sound, even if it is possible. The Server scope would be better for resources that you want to share across applications.

You might even want to consider whether the two applications should actually be one single application with two small sub-applications.

Comment: When I have a sub application, then it has it's own application scope, and I have to implement the same solution to access it.  This is my experience anyway when I have a parent folder with an application.cfc, and a sub-folder with it's own application.cfc.  Perhaps you could post an example where the sub application shares the parent application scope?

Comment: I should also say that the reason I want to do this is because I have one application that consumes services from another application.  I need to invoke CFC's from App1 in App2, but have them execute in the App1 scope instead of the App2 scope as they do when you use cfinvoke or instantiate them directly.

Comment: This really sounds like a candidate for everything being one application. One way to accomplish the shared application scope would be to use extended an application.cfc in the subdirectories that contain each app. The applications could have any custom app.cfc stuff they need but should still maintain a common application scope.

Comment: Could you post what you mean by "an extended application.cfc"?  I've tried having subdirectories with their own application.cfc's, even given them the same application name, and they still do not share scopes.  I have different mappings for the sub-application, I imagine this might make a difference where the page context is concerned.

Comment: Here's a good blog post on some of the finer points of extending App.cfcs: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1179-Ask-Ben-Extending-Application-cfc-And-OnRequestStart-With-SUPER.htm Courtesy of Ben Nadel. He explains it very well and lays out some examples that should help with your specific case.

Answer (score 5):

I put my answer together from two sources.  First, Ben Nadel's [Massive Exploration](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/758-ColdFusion-GetPageContext-Massive-Exploration.htm) of the ColdFusion PageContext object (Thanks Ben).  Second, the ColdFusion help page on [Interoperating with JSP pages and servlets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-786c.html#WS96891155-4351-45ea-9D0A-30C329F49FBE).  Put the two together and I get this:

Directory structure:

```
Root
 |_ App1
   |_ Application.cfc
   |_ index.cfm
 |_ App2
   |_ Application.cfc
   |_ index.cfm
```

App1/Application.cfc:

```
component
{
 this.name="App1";
 this.application.foo = "bar"
}
```

App2/Application.cfc:

```
component
{
 this.name="App2"
}
```

App2/index.cfm

```
<cfscript>
writeDump(getPageContext().getFusionContext().getServletContext().getAttribute('App1'))
</cfscript>
```

After hitting the index.cfm in the App1 directory, you can see the application scope from app1 dumped in the index of app2.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with @Daniel about the architecture.
@Ryan's answer is a good one.

I thought I would offer the alternative I thought of, which has a few advantages, and a few drawbacks.

Basically, any data to be shared between the apps can be written to the server scope.  For example:

```
// In App 1
application.foo = "bar";
server.sharedData.app1.fpp = "bar";

// In App 2
application.bar = "foo";
server.sharedData.app2.bar = "foo";
// Use shared data from App 1
writeOutput(server.sharedData.app1.foo);
```

Advantages:

- simpler syntax
- shared data available to all applications

Disadvantages

- You have to remeber to update the server.sharedData scope whenever you update the application scoe.
- be careful choosing your master struct key.  You don't want to overwerite existing server scope data.
- Shared data is available to all applications.  :-)

Anyway, this was my first thought but after reading @Ryan's answer, I'd probaly just write a UDF that takes an application name and a var name, and use it as a facade for what he did.

But seriously, consider whether sharing data across appications is smarter/wiser than merging them.

Comment: This is a good solution, thanks for the example.  In my particular situation I am wary about setting server scope variables because I have little control over the server, but this is a good solution for someone who has that control.  I like the idea of putting it behind a facade, I'll have to implement that in my application.

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion application scopes are handled by the ApplicationScopeTracker java class.

You can access an application scope of another app.

It's undocumented and I wouldn't use it for anything in production!

Lets say you have 2 web apps with the names `app1` and `app2`.

Run this on `app1` to access `app2`'s application scope:

```
<cfscript>
appTracker = createObject( 'java', 'coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScopeTracker' );
app2 = appTracker.getApplicationScope('app2');
</cfscript>
```

If the `app2` application has not started, or has timed out, `getApplicationScope()` will return undefined.

You can also get an enumeration of all current application scopes using `appTracker.getApplicationKeys()`